# Should i use csv or sqlite3 to make a database in python?

Tags: python, database, csv, sqlite

For my school project I have to create a program which uses a database

My program will look at files in documents and put them into tables based on what type of file they are. In the tables I will have information about the file like **name**, **size** in bytes and **date** modified.

**My questions:**

- For this project **would it be better to use `sqlite3` or `csv`?**
- **How are they different and which is more popular?**

I want to make it as efficient as possible so I can get a good mark!

Comment: Recommendations of off-site resources are not suitable topics for this forum.  But . . . csv is a file format and sqlite is a database engine.  The two are very different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to clarify, CSV is a file; SQLite is a popular choice as embedded database software for local/client storage in application software [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite).

in your case SQLite, is going to make it easier to query a subset of your data.